# Difference between Parent.Controls.RemoveAt() and Control.Dispose() in C# WinApp

Tags: c#, winforms

In my application, some controls are added and removed in runtime.

```
//Form level variable-
Dictionary<string, PictureBox> pictureBoxes = new Dictionary<string, PictureBox>();


private void ToggelPing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
   groupBox.Controls.Add(pb); //adding to a GroupBox
   pictureBoxes.Add(key, pb); //add to the Dictionary<> variable
}
```

While removing the PictureBox control added on above, currently I'm using the following code-

```
groupBox.Controls.RemoveAt(index); 
if (pictureBoxes.ContainsKey(key))
{
    pictureBoxes.Remove(key);
}
```

To remove the control, may I **ONLY** use the following code ?

```
if (pictureBoxes.ContainsKey(key))
{
    PictureBox pb= pictureBoxes[key]
    pictureBoxes.Remove(key);
    pb.Dispose(); //Disposing the control
}
```

Instead of

```
groupBox.Controls.RemoveAt(index);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently yes, we can see somewhere in Dispose method of [Control.cs](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/fx/src/WinForms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control@cs/1305376/Control@cs), that the Control removes itself from its parent:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) { 
    ...
    ...
    if (parent != null) { 
        parent.Controls.Remove(this);   
    } 
    ...
    ...
}
```

But you need to do that carefully, making sure you do not hold a reference to the control somewhere else to avoid accessing the disposed Control.